# A necessary condition for when a sheaf of ideals correspond to a closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Ravi Vakil's Foundation of Algebraic Geometry exercise $8.1(G)$ asks the following: Suppose, $\mathcal I_{X/Y}$ is a sheaf of ideals corresponding to a closed embedding $\pi : X \to Y$.Suppose $SpecB \subset Y$ is an open affine subscheme, and $f \in B$.Show that the natural map $(I(B))_f \to I(B_f)$ is an isomorphism.(Here $I(B)=$ kernel of the morphism $\mathcal O_Y \to \pi_{*}\mathcal O_X$, evaluated on $SpecB$)

$(1)$ I have been able to solve the problem assuming that  $\mathcal I_{X/Y} = $ Kernel of the morphism $\mathcal O_Y \to \pi_{*}\mathcal O_X$.But then $\mathcal I_{X/Y}$  is becoming a very particular sheaf of ideal of $Y$ namely the ideal sheaf corresponding to $X$ whereas in the question they are talking about "a" sheaf of ideal corresponding to that closed embedding.So my question is What is exactly meant by " $\mathcal I_{X/Y}$ is a sheaf of ideals corresponding to a closed embedding $\pi : X \to Y$".

$(2)$ Since $I(B)$ is an ideal,I hope localization is also an ideal and not necessarily a ring.So my question is What is exactly meant by "isomorphism between $2$ ideals".(while solving the problem I have produced a natural map which is injective and surjective )

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: (1)The sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{X/Y}$ is indeed the kernel you mention: this is defined in p.226 of Vakil's notes. Note that this is the ideal sheaf in $Y$ of the image of the closed immersion. (2) the isomorphism is of modules (really, quasi-coherent sheaves). It helps to consider the meaning of the isomorphism.

Comment: @Artur Araujo,thank you for your answer,but then you yourself mention :"the" ideal sheaf in $Y$ of the image of the closed immersion.That was exactly my point that it should be "the" sheaf of ideal instead of "a" sheaf of ideal..Please correct me if I am missing something

Comment: I'm not exactly sure i understand your question, but maybe this helps: the unique ideal sheaf that gives the image a reduced scheme structure.